# Vim8 cannot delete letters

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I installed a vim 8.1 on the cluster I am using in my home folder. I also installed a number of plugins including YouCompleteMe. I then made an alias so that I can open the vim easier.

However, I found that my vim cannot delete letters very well. When I am writing I can delete what I just typed. But if I move the cursor to other places, then it cannot delete letters at all, unless I type in something at first.

I am using a Scientific Linux system developed by the Fermi Lab.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the default configuration of the [`:help 'backspace'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27bs%27) option. If this doesn't contain `start`, you cannot remove characters over the start of insertion by pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, only what got inserted before. Removal of characters via the `x` or `d` commands ([`:help deleting`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#deleting)) should always work - anywhere. Else, you have a serious misconfiguration should inspect your `~/.vimrc` and re-add plugins one by one.

If you're new to Vim (and using backspace for deletion in insert mode is a typical approach of people used to other, modeless editors), you should spend 30 minutes on the `vimtutor` that comes with it (see [`:help vimtutor`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_01.txt.html#vimtutor)). Then, there are several good resources, cheatsheets, and vi / Vim tutorials out there on the net. http://vimcasts.org/ has several short entertaining episodes that go beyond the basics.

Your problem could be fixed by putting

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

into your `~/.vimrc`. Also have a look at [`:help defaults.vim`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim); by including that instead, you'll get other goodies and recommended settings as well! (The reason for the odd defaults is backwards compatibility.)